# My ajax request

Tags: ajaxform

Ajax is not populating my table with all the information from json encode values  are `{"name":"1","...":"Value"}` fields with string values and the integers are not.

```
var idvalue = $("#modal-name"), 

 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
          url: "ajax.php",
          data: {
                  action: "getBudget",
                  userId : userId
                },
         success : function(data) {
          //parse result as JSON
          var res = JSON.parse(data);

          //update modal fields
          idvalue . text(res.name);
          // other ID to populate
        }
});
```

Comment: What kind of errors you getting (in your console)? What is not working?

Comment: i dont get any errors i have this json data, but #Nathan Schwarz answered the question {"budgetID":"1","outstationID":"1","status":"Active","pointman":"1223"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to remove the space and replace the "," by a ";" in the first line: `var idvalue = $("#modal-name");`. It will resolve some of your problems.